# MKMapView detect if user location in region boundaries

Tags: ios, algorithm, mkmapview, cllocation

[image]

We display in region (white overlay) pins (f.e shops) around 500 meters near user location.

request to api looks like:

```
...shops/?lat,lon=x&radius
```

When user location is updated, we don't want to send request for "shops" each time.

What is good algorithm to keep updated all "shops" near user location in 500 meters when he moves, but keep as little as possible requests?

I'm assuming one possible algorithm is getting fake location with distance from user location respecting direction (like green circle).

So that we can get new "shops" and next user location update will be ignored. Of-course we need to check somehow if user still inside region for which we already have "shops"

Could you help me probably with algorithm or better one, or rough implementation, or at least with brief steps.

Thanks in advance